# App Engine Bulk Data Upload- Authentication Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, bigtable

When I try to upload data using appcfg.py I get an authentication error regardless of my login details being completely correct.

```
    appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --filename=/output.csv --kind=AutoCompleteIndex .
Application: qwertifyy; version: dev.
Uploading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20100808.205421
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20100808.205421.sql3
[INFO    ] Connecting to qwertifyy.appspot.com/remote_api
Please enter login credentials for qwertifyy.appspot.com
Email: matt2224@gmail.com
Password for matt2224@gmail.com: 
[INFO    ] Authentication Failed
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: Do the same credentials work if you are just deploying a new version (appcfg update) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using OpenID? If so, it appears that remote_api doesn't work with OpenID:

http://blog.notdot.net/2010/06/Using-remote-api-with-OpenID-authentication

Comment: He's using an @gmail account. How could that be an openid issue?

Comment: @Travis: You can set up your app for federated login - then it will use openid for handling google logins (and other openid logins), instead of the default google login method.

Comment: Yeah, I was using opened. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this issue when trying to authenticate with a "Google Apps" account.

Get around the issue by setting up another "Google" account that can be used with Google App Engine and using this to authenticate with instead. You can do this from Dashboard > Administration > Permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong options. I ran into the same problem by specifying the directory.

There are plenty of pitfalls in the process. After spending much time on something so elementary, I wrote a tutorial to get people through the process quickly and without any fuss.

http://heliodorj.blogspot.com/2011/09/google-app-engine-bulk-download-and.html